# Restarting a Zebra printer using ZPL

Tags: restart, zebra-printers, printers, zpl

Is there a ZPL command to simply restart a Zebra printer?
So far I could only find the ~JR command, which to me doesn't look like what I'm searching for. I just need a way to issue a restart to the printer without resetting any of its configuration.

Comment: `~JR` is the command you are looking for.  Per the docs: Issuing a ~JR command performs the same function as a manual power-on reset.

Comment: Correct ~JR is right - ^JUF resets the configuration

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if you face a scenario **when you can't send ZPLs** to the printer, the way to do it is to use the SDK (Not ZPL)

If you have an application that connects with the printer and is using the printer API using SDK, you can use it to reset the Printer.

> Note: This will work only when you can't even access the Web interface
> of the printer.

Here is the Documentation of that specific method:
[Interface ToolsUtil : reset()](https://techdocs.zebra.com/link-os/2-14/pc/content/com/zebra/sdk/printer/ToolsUtil.html#reset())